# Django CharField with no max length

Tags: django, model, django-forms

I have a frontend that will be sending bas64 images, I will put those very large strings on a variable and send it to a form. What kind of `FormField` can I use?

The regular `CharFields` need a `max_length`. Since it is a very large string, I don't know the length it could have.

Answer (score 52):

Maybe [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#textfield) could be the right choice.

Comment: @alejoss If so please check my answer as solution :)

Comment: TextField is good but it displays as a TextArea in admin. Is there a better alternative ?